# Getting records of ages under 24 between two dates in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a visits table

```
visits
dob[varchar(50)]    visitdate[Date]           name[varchar(16)]    
09/16/2001          2022-11-01                             A
09/26/1966          2022-11-01                             B
09/21/1999          2022-11-02                             C
09/24/2000          2022-11-02                             D
```

I need to get records of those below the age of 24 by the visit date

Currently, I am using the filter to get records

Here are below code

```
function get_age_group($dob, $visitDate)
{
    $dob        = explode("/", $dob);
    $dob        = new DateTime($dob[2] . '-' . $dob[0] . '-' . $dob[1]);
    $visitDate  = new DateTime($visitDate);
    $diff       = $visitDate->diff($dob);
    return $diff->y;
}

// here is query
$visits = DB::table('visits')->get();

foreach ($visits as $row)
{
    $age = get_age_group($row->dob, $row->visitdate);
    if(($age < 24))
    {
        //push the data
    }
}
```

I want to get all records where the age is under 24 between two dates(dob, visitdate)

// here is query
$visits = DB::table('visits')->where(?)->get();

I want to remove the above foreach function and want to add where clause in the query to get the records under 24 years.

Comment: What is actual DBMS - MySQL or SQL Server? remove unrelated tag.

Comment: I am using the MySQL Server

Comment: Why DOB is stored as string and not as DATE?

Comment: @Akina
Sure I will update it to DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE visits (dob VARCHAR(50), visitdate DATE, name VARCHAR(16));
INSERT INTO visits VALUES
('09/16/2001',          '2022-11-01',                             'A'),
('09/26/1966',          '2022-11-01',                             'B'),
('09/21/1999',          '2022-11-02',                             'C'),
('09/24/2000',          '2022-11-02',                             'D');
```

```
SELECT *
FROM visits
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%m\/%d\/%Y') + INTERVAL 24 YEAR > visitdate;
```

| dob | visitdate | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09/16/2001 | 2022-11-01 | A |
| 09/21/1999 | 2022-11-02 | C |
| 09/24/2000 | 2022-11-02 | D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vuAtjbAh)

If `DOB` contains incorrect date value (including the value with excess leading chars) then according row won't be returned. I recommend you to alter this column's datatype to DATE.